# Hide long select list array in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a select list in my controller which is an array, but it is very long (some 400 lines) - is there any way I can yield this out or something in its own file?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this.

You could store those 400 lines in:

- plain text format (some_array.txt) and load them using File utils
- json format (some_array.json) and load them using JSON
- yaml format (some_array.yaml) and load them using YAML
- etc

Following is an example using the first approach of storing in a plain text format and loading it in a class constant so that they are loaded only once in the production.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  SOME_ARRAY = File.readlines("{Rails.root}/config/some_array.txt").collect(&:strip).freeze

  def some_action
    @some_array = SOME_ARRAY
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..................

**In your config/initializers**

Create a file file_name.rb and Add your Array in this file for example:

**In your config/initializers/filename.rb**

SOMEARRAY = [1,2,3,4,5]

Now restart your App and call this Array in your App where you want.

Hope this will work for you